# Very strange behavior after http get

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

At one component I have an http call returning ok the desired data and I can iterate normally with *ngFor. The code is :

```
    getData() {
    return this.http.get(environment.myURL).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.myData = (response);
      } ,
      (error) => console.log('Error -> ', error)
    );
  }
```

But on other component with this same code I got a response like : Response with status: 200 OK for URL...

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Are you sure you are processing the data on the same way? Do you use Http service or HttpClient service?

Comment: Especially, do you call `response.json()` in both components? I think the response you are referring to is from the `HttpResponse` wrapper provided by angular (returned from the http call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `Http` service in one component, and `HttpClient` service in the other one. When using `HttpClient`, you will get JSON response parsed automatically. When using just `Http`, you need to call `response.json()` first.

Comment: Was exactly this. Thank you !